# AngularJS pass variable through to a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to pass a variable or text through to a template so that it shows the value inside my template.

I come across [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/2kcw9xbw/) which shows it working but it uses `ng-repeat`. Is there a simplere way to do this without using `ng-repeat`?

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['John']" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
<div ng-repeat="name in ['Jack']" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial.html">
   <div>The name is {{ name }}</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Using just one div?? `<div ng-repeat="name in ['John','Jack']" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>`

Comment: The above divs would be split to other parts of a page so no need for ng-repeat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f97keutL/

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial.html">
   <div>The name is {{ name }}</div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John"; 
});
```

You just set the variable in the scope, and include the template?

Comment: I come across `<div ng-init="name= 'John'" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>` Which seems to work. Could I get a second opinion?

Comment: Second opinion: Using ng-init is rather discouraged. It is encouraged to use controllers to do this initialization. The reason being a simple separation of concern between how and where a model should be initialized. And controllers have primary job of making the model available to the view. Views should not manipulate or even initialize any models.

Comment: You could do ng-init, but in my experience it's rare to use it, depends entirely on use case though.  In general the html should describe what to show (i.e. show the users name), and your model (the javascript) would contain the value (what the users name is).  Using ng-init puts the value in the view, which I would generally advise against.

Comment: @dave So I have a controller like this *(let's say `$scope` is `s` for brevity)*: `s.gridOne; s.gridTwo; s.notAGrid;` and I want to create a template to show just the grids. How could I send just the grids? I can't do `ng-repeat = "grid in s"` because one of the elements are not a grid.

Comment: @Travis s.grids = [s.gridOne, s.gridTwo], ng-repeat = "grid in s.grids"